# Check, if a file has changed, before downloading it from SFTP server using Apache Ant

Tags: ant, sftp

I'm using an Ant `<scp>` task to download files from an SFTP server. I'd like to check, whether the file exists locally and, if yes, if it is the same as the file on the server. (How) it is possible to compare timestamps or hashes before downloading it?

```
<scp file="${ftp.user}:${ftp.password}@${ftp.url}:/my/path/*"
      failonerror="false"
      verbose="yes"
      sftp="true"
      trust="true"
      todir="${target.dir}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with a checksum file:

```
<checksum file="${temp.dir}${file.separator}my.zip" algorithm="SHA-512" property="zip-checksum"/>
<scp file="${ftp.user}:${ftp.password}@${ftp.url}:/my/path/my.zip.asc"
  failonerror="false"
  verbose="no"
  sftp="true"
  trust="true"
  todir="${temp.dir}"/>
<loadfile srcfile="${temp.dir}/my.zip.asc" property="my-other-zip">
  <filterchain>
    <striplinebreaks/>
    <trim/>
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
<checksum file="${temp.dir}${file.separator}my.zip" property="${my-other-zip}" verifyProperty="zip-checksum-match"/>
<if>
  <equals arg1="${zip-checksum}" arg2="${my-other-zip}"/>
  <then>
    <echo level="info">Checksum of my.zip (local) is equal to my.zip (server). Skipping...</echo>
  </then>
  <else>
    <echo level="info">Checksum of my.zip (local) is not equal to my.zip (server). Get new zip...</echo>
    <scp file="${ftp.user}:${ftp.password}@${ftp.url}:/my/path/my.zip"
      failonerror="false"
      verbose="no"
      sftp="true"
      trust="true"
      todir="${temp.dir}"/>
  </else>
</if>
```